# Qt - Stretch frame borders to be uniform in window

Tags: qt, go

I'm having some trouble understanding how Qt assigns sizes to frames when there are several frames in a window in a grid pattern (using the grid layout). As you can see I have several frames but I want the smaller frames to extend horizontally (east and west) so that they are all almost touching each other and the window borders. I'm using the qt binding for Golang by the way, so my code below is Go but if anyone can offer any help using C++ or just an explanation of what I'm doing wrong it would be GREATLY appreciated.

What I want:
[Written in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWs0Q.png)

What I have:
[Written in Go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOZgu.png)

This is my code for the first frame that is within my main frame (process_frame):

`

```
// Cancel Reason subframe
frame_cancel_reason := widgets.NewQFrame(nil, 0)
frame_cancel_reason.SetStyleSheet(FRAME_BORDER + colors["gold"])
frame_cancel_reason_layout := widgets.NewQGridLayout(frame_cancel_reason)   
process_frame_layout.AddWidget2(frame_cancel_reason, 0, 0, core.Qt__AlignJustify)

label_cancel_reason := widgets.NewQLabel2("Please select a cancellation reason", frame_cancel_reason, 0)
label_cancel_reason.SetFont(FONT_MAIN_LABEL)
label_cancel_reason.SetStyleSheet(NO_FRAME_BORDER)
frame_cancel_reason_layout.AddWidget2(label_cancel_reason, 0, 0, core.Qt__AlignCenter)

cancel_reason_options := []string{"Lost Business (with removals)", "Lost Business (no removals)", "Store Closing"}
frame_cancel_reason_options := widgets.NewQFrame(nil, 0)
cancel_reason_otions_layout := widgets.NewQGridLayout(frame_cancel_reason_options)
frame_cancel_reason_options.SetLayout(cancel_reason_otions_layout)
frame_cancel_reason_options.SetStyleSheet(NO_FRAME_BORDER)
cancel_reason_group := widgets.NewQButtonGroup(nil)
for i, cancel_reason_option := range cancel_reason_options {
    r := widgets.NewQRadioButton2(cancel_reason_option, nil)
    r.SetFont(FONT_ITEM)
    r.SetStyleSheet(NO_FRAME_BORDER)
    cancel_reason_group.AddButton(r, i)
    cancel_reason_otions_layout.AddWidget2(r, i, 0, core.Qt__AlignLeading)
}
frame_cancel_reason_layout.AddWidget2(frame_cancel_reason_options, 1, 0, core.Qt__AlignCenter)
```

`

I've gone through the Qt documentation, searched stackoverflow, and googled but can't seem to find an answer.

**Update**
So I came up with the following solution, but I'm thinking there has to be a more elegant way. Basically, what I did was grab each frame and manually resize it (by adjusting margins) based on the size of the main window:

```
// Sizing - So all frames are more uniform
new_frame_width := (process_frame.FrameGeometry().Width() / 2)
children := process_frame.FindChildren("", core.Qt__FindDirectChildrenOnly)
for _, child := range children {
    if child.MetaObject().ClassName() == "QFrame" {
        actual_child := widgets.NewQFrameFromPointer(child.Pointer())
        child_width := actual_child.FrameGeometry().Width()
        new_margin := (new_frame_width - child_width) / 2
        actual_child.SetContentsMargins(new_margin, 0, new_margin, 0)

    }
```

Comment: Something interesting going on, please post whole code and specify qt version, and try to call `layout.invalidate()` on outer layout after `show()`